# Expressão regular case insensitive em um dataframe

Tags: python, regex, pandas, dataframe

Possuo um dataframe com alguns tweets que foram coletados de acordo com a palavra chave.

Como faço por exemplo pra extrair de uma vez apenas as linhas com `#flamengo` e todas suas variações, como `#Flamengo`, `#FLAMENGO`, etc?

Usei:

```
data['text'].str.extract('(#flamengo)')
```

Mas retorna apenas os tweets escritos em minúsculo.

Answer (score 1):

Segundo a [documentação](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html), é possível passar um segundo parâmetro para `extract`, contendo *flags* que alteram o comportamento da expressão regular.

Neste caso, basta usar a [*flag* `re.I`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.I), que torna  regex *case insensitive* (não diferencia maiúsculas de minúsculas):

```
import re

data['text'].str.extract('(#flamengo)', re.I)
```

---

Também é possível usar o modificador *inline* `(?i)` na própria expressão, que tem o mesmo efeito da *flag*:

```
data['text'].str.extract('((?i)#flamengo)')

# ou
data['text'].str.extract('((?i:#flamengo))')
```

---

A [outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/447059/112052) sugeriu usar `[f|F]` para pegar tanto um "f" minúsculo quanto maiúsculo. Só que essa expressão também pega o caractere `|`, [veja](https://regex101.com/r/eYws9k/1). Se for seguir aquela ideia, então o certo seria `[fF][lL]...`. Mas usar as flags é mais simples.

Comment: a outra resposta está errada. é uma resposta típica de  quem conhece um martelo, e trata tudo como prego - (e nem o martelo conhece bem, já que dá pra colocar a flag de case-insensitive, como você fez)

Comment: se não fosse possível resolver o problema com parâmetros apenas na expressão regular - vamos supor que você resolva que tem que remover os acentos também, e achar tanto "árvore" quanto "arvore" - o correto é criar uma outra coluna no dataframe, usando o méotodo  "apply" que tenha o texto normalizado - (isso é: acentos removidos, convertido pra minúsculas, espaços e caracteres que não sejam interessantes convertidos para "_") - e buscar na outra coluna.